# Perl Moose exception when invoking a reference to an attribute's writer method

Tags: perl, reference, moose, writer

I am trying to pass a reference to an attribute's writer method to another class method. The setter method is apparently invoked since the print statement is executed. However, the following error results:

```
Attribute (dir) is required, so cannot be set to undef at Test.pm line 51
Test::_validateDir('Test=HASH(0x2270be0)', 'CODE(0x22a90f8)') called at test.pm line 37
Test::BUILD('test_moose=HASH(0x2270be0)', 'HASH(0x1879728)') called at generated method (unknown origin) line 50
Test:new('Test', dir=>'my_bin') called at ./test_moose.pl line 26
```

Is there a reason why a reference to the generated writer method cannot be taken or is there a different or better way to do this in Moose?

Here's the code:

```
package Test;
use Moose;
use File::Spec;

has 'dir' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1, writer '_set_dir',);

sub BUILD {
    my ($self, $hr) = @_;
    $self->_validateDir(\&_set_dir);
}

sub _validate_dir {
    my ($self, $setter) = @_;
    my $dir = File::Spec->rel2abs($self->dir, '/home/me');
    if (! -e $dir) {
       print "creating directory\n";
       #create directory
    }
    &$setter($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it right to call the setter as a regular sub? Shouldn't you pass `$self` as a first argument?

Comment: I've undeleted your answer now... perhaps you should rephrase it so it doesn't get deleted (again) for looking like a comment. Also an interesting read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131959/should-i-not-flag-a-rhetorical-question-posted-as-an-answer

Comment: Ah, thanks! I don’t think we should be so anal about the language as to delete rhetorical questions that are obviously an attempt for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, a reference to a method does *not* include the associated object.  When you call the reference, you must supply the object (or class, if it's a class method) as the first parameter.

```
&$setter($self, $dir);
```

Or, (equivalent when `$setter` is a code reference but more idiomatic):

```
$self->$setter($dir);
```

The reason you get "Attribute (dir) is required, so cannot be set to undef" is that Perl thinks that `$dir` is the object and the value is missing (and thus `undef`), and it apparently does that check before it notices that `$dir` isn't an object.